# Premature optimization and Premature pessimization related to C++ coding standards

Tags: c++, coding-style

Herb Sutter's *C++ coding standards* says to avoid `Premature optimization` and `Premature pessimization`. But I feel both is doing the same thing. So expecting some help to clarify these two concept with the difference between them. If you come-up with some examples, It will be more benefit for others.
[Here](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) is a good explanation about `Premature optimization`. But I couldn't find any for `Premature pessimization`

Comment: By the way, Knut said this in 1974. Nowadays premature optimization mostly means do not compile release version prematurely. Because compiler would optimize the 99% of the code (including the optimizations made by the programmer).

Comment: @SChepurin It certainly doesn't. Premature optimization means to optimize parts of the code (by e.g. writing supposedly fast low-level code, possibly including bit-fiddling, inline-assembly etc.) without having firm evidence that it is actually performance critical.

Comment: @Michael Wild - How does this contradict with what i said?

Comment: @SChepurin Well, the term "premature optimization" doesn't have anything to do with compiler settings. It's about manually optimizing the code.

Comment: @Michael Wild - Well, and i say that after 39 years "manually optimizing the code" is, say, "premature" in 99% of the cases.

Comment: @SChepurin that being exactly my point. "manually optimizing" the code is what the term "premature optimization" refers to. not turning on some optimization flag in your compile settings.

Comment: @SChepurin, I'd say that anyone that seriously believes they can comment about 99% of all cases of optimization occurring in programming today is misguided in the extreme.

Comment: @Shane MacLaughlin - It is okay if you think this way.

Comment: A better way of saying is to combine the quotes from Donald Knuth and Jon Bentley. In other words, optimization is a heavy undertaking, and it is more prone to losing value due to future technology changes because today's optimization techniques may become meaningless or counterproductive on tomorrow's hardware, compiler, or operating systems. However, almost every software endeavour is a heavy undertaking - porting an application to a new operating system (e.g. Android), to a new CPU, to a new kind of neuromorphic/quantum/optical chip, etc. It may be a flop or it may be a blockbuster.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What he means by premature pessimisation, I think, is just the opposite of premature optimisation: a fundamental disregard of which data structures and algorithms to use.

Premature optimisation is often concerned with minute details of algorithms that can well be tweaked later and don’t need to be paid attention to at the beginning.

Premature pessimisation, by contrast, concerns the high-level design of code architecture: a fundamentally inefficient interface for your library for instance cannot be fixed later by optimising, since the public interface is pretty much cast in stone.

Comment: How often do you see people quoting the idea that you shouldn't prematurely optimize and use it as an excuse to write crappy, slow code?  I recently inherited a project where some code would take well over a minute to complete and then replacing it with some basic optimization that reduced it's run time to less than a second.  It's a shame that developers don't know the difference.  I will be sure to share a link to your answer to the next person who tries to use that as an excuse for bad coding.

Answer (score 10):

What Herb means is that when you are faced with two equally readable options, always choose the most efficient one.

Using `std::vector::reserve()` or the best standard container or algorithm is not premature optimization. However, not using them would be *premature pessimisation*.

*Premature optimization* is when you sacrifice readability for the sake of some "optimization" that might even not be worth it. Use a profiler for that.

Answer (score 2):

> Defining pass-by-value parameters when pass-by-reference is
> appropriate

is one of the simplest examples of avoiding *premature pessimization*. It costs nothing and just becomes second nature, and can save you some performance pitfalls.

Assuming you are referring to this book - *C++ Coding Standards: 101 Rules, Guidelines, and Best Practices. October 2004 ISBN: 0321113586* - items 9 and 25 give a few examples:

---

9. Don’t pessimize prematurely

---

25. Take parameters appropriately by value, (smart) pointer, or reference

---

Answer (score 1):

There are both small and large scale choices to be made when programming.

Pessimisation is when write code in a way that "prevents the compiler from doing a good job". A typical example would be to not place functions in a place that allows them to be inlined, when the function is REALLY small and simple (a {s,g}etter for example). This can make the function take 10x the time it should take, and it's such a simple thing to "get right".

A pessimisation that I've found a few times on this site is to use "a /= 2;" when "a >>= 1" is equally suitable. If we know that `a` is not negative, then shift left and divide have the same effect, but even when the compiler is optimising the divide, it nearly always produces more code to cope with "it may be negative" situation - and that extra code can be a real performance hit in some cases.

Premature optimisation is when you unroll loops or otherwise make the code more complicated simply because you don't trust the compiler to do a good job - typically with no evidence that it won't do a good job.

Another example would be "not using `std::vector`", but your own `expandable array` because "vector is too slow", without even having tested the code using `std::vector`.

Comment: I agree with the first paragraph but I think you lost it at the second. Replacing `a /2` by `a >> 1` is *exactly* the kind of premature optimisation that you should leave to a compiler. Write readable code. If you want do divide by two, *do that*. Don’t get all cryptic on me on less you can prove that this piece of code is performance-critical **and** the compiler will produce less optimal code.

Comment: Have you looked at the difference between `a / 2` and `a >> 1`? You'd be surprised. I agree, that if it's something done once in the beginning of `main`, then it will make no difference. But writing code that is longer just because some beginner can't read it is also a bad idea. If someone is a professional C/C++ programmer and don't understand `a >> 1` is the same as `a / 2` (for positive values at least), then they are probably not a very experienced programmer (in C at least).

Comment: I have looked at the assembler generated by various compilers, and any decent compiler takes care of using shifts instead of multiplication and divisions where appropriate, and goes way beyond what regular programmers would come up with. It is the job of the compiler writer to figure out the best way to do these kinds of micro-optimization. Just to give an example, gcc, when asked to do 23*i, actually does the equivalent of "i*3 << 3 - i". This is even with -O0!

Comment: @itub: Sometimes `a /= 2;` will turn into exactly `a >>= 1`, but sometimes it doesn't - it depends on the use of `a` after, what target processor and several other factors. And I just discovered the other day that clang (likely other compilers too) understands a loop that does `for(s = 0, i = 0; i < n; i++, s+=i);`, and converts it to `s = n*(n-1)/2;`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd tend to think that premature pessimization is simply the misinterpretation of performance requirements that leads to premature opimization.  i.e. you incorrectly assume your code will not perform fast enough or use too many resources (pessimism) so you optimize where it is not necessary.

With the advent of more and many huge datasets, I tend to see to reverse more often, i.e. lack of sufficient pessimism leading to selection of algorithms that will not scale to meet user requirements.  This is often coupled with the belief that compiler optimization is some kind of substitute for poor algorithm selection.