# Which search algorithm to use for item list under 30?

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures

I have a sorted array of 30 real numbers. The numbers are spread evenly. I want to search a number in this array. Currently, I am using linear search algorithm. In order to increase performance of my application, I need to use better search algorithm. Which search algorithm shall I use Or on what basis shall I choose 'best' algorithm ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since the array is sorted you can use [Binary Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search) which will be the fastest method.

Comment: try hash, or binary search

Comment: you will not improve the speed of your application when changing the search algo for 30 elements.

Comment: Thx Matthew. I will use Binary search.

Comment: @AlexWien : Just out of curiosity, when will binary search be effective ? What is the minimum number of items you should have if you want to use binary search ?

Comment: This depends on your cpu, and your environment, CPU chache size, programming language, compiler. You can measure it, some algorithms have such a limit hard coded, usually near 20- 30, they switch to linear search or (another algoritm) when this limit os not reached. I think 30 is near to that limit, but one ha sto measure it, or if not relevant just leave it at linear search, if you dont do it 10.000 times per seconds. Binry search always works, so there is no drawback. This only interresting in high load situations.

Comment: @user24669666: Its 1 :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, are you entirely sure the search really represents a bottleneck? Optimize your schedule before your code, make sure that you are optimizing where it really is worth it. You could easily be surprised to notice something much simpler that takes longer. I recommend profiling to make sure. [VerySleepy](http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy) generally does the job for me if you're using C++.

Now, if you notice that the search really represents a bottleneck, you could switch to a Binary search, as suggested in the comments (in C++, `std::binary_search` from `<algorithm>`). You could also switch containers for a *hast table*, but this depends on your needs and situation.

Profile, benchmark, pick what fits best for your situation.

Comment: You are totally right, but if the array is indeed sorted it makes no sense to do a linear search in it, when he can easily do a binary search. He should have done a binary search in the first place, otherwise he's pessimizing prematurely. (See http://stackoverflow.com/q/15875252/96780)

Comment: Thx for the answer. The code on which I am working is already written by somebody else. The function which is doing the search thing is getting called from some paint function. I am trying to  improve painting performance, so was going through the code and found that linear search is used.
I will try to use binary search and will do the profiling to actually check performance. Thx again :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify a language, and the fastest approach for an array of just 30 elements will probably vary by language.

However, if you write a test C# program you will find that for a RELEASE build, using `BinarySearch()` will be faster. C++ and other languages may give a different result.

The following test code searches for a non-existent element in an array of 30 ints using linear and binary search. Because the element doesn't exist, both searches will take the maximum number of operations. Results will differ for successful searches.

Results are like this:

```
IndexOf()      took 00:00:00.5463193
BinarySearch() took 00:00:00.3035060
```

Indicating that Binary Search is somewhat faster, at least for C# when the target element doesn't exist.

```
int[] array = new int[30];
int count = 10000000;

for (int trial = 0; trial < 4; ++trial)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        Array.IndexOf(array, 1);

    Console.WriteLine("IndexOf() took " + sw.Elapsed);

    sw.Restart();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        Array.BinarySearch(array, 1);

    Console.WriteLine("BinarySearch() took " + sw.Elapsed);
}
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. How language will have effect on searching ? Couldn't understand. I am using C++ btw.

Comment: @user2469666 For short arrays, the overhead of setting up the binary search and doing it might dominate the time in some languages. So in C/C++ it might be faster to do a linear search. The best thing to do is to write some code to time it. Note that C++ has a binary search that you can use with `vector`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/af0b55bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You need to do some timings to establish what is fastest. This may vary by platform, programming language, CPU architecture, the data you have etc. It is also worth performing timings on the whole program, using a profiler or inserting your own timing calls, as you see fit.

To test what technique is fastest in C++, I ran a simple test program to compare the performance of

1. linear search on an unsorted array (`std::find`), O(n), against
2. binary chop on sorted data (using `std::lower_bound`), O(log n), against
3. a linear search on sorted data, O(n).

A linear search on sorted data stops as soon as it finds the match, so if the element you're looking for is in the array, its expected cost is half that of linear search on an unsorted array. In my test program, half of the cases I looked for weren't in the array, so you'd expect the cost of this to be around 75% of the cost of a linear search on unsorted data. Of course, sorting the array will add considerably to the runtime if you have to do it frequently!

In the graph below,

- the red circles are the ratio of the cost of binary search to linear search on an unsorted array, and
- the black circles are the ratio of the cost of linear search on sorted data to unsorted data.

[image]

You can see in this case at least, there isn't much to choose between the techniques at n=30, and unless profiling shows that you have a real performance bottleneck, it might be best to follow the keep it simple rule, and, if you don't have to have sorted data, just do a linear search on unsorted data, so you don't have the additional constraint of having sorted data (or do linear search on sorted data if the sorting is a reasonable constraint).

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) if your numbers are sorted. As compared to Linear Search(`O(n)`) it will search in `O(log n)` time

Comment: big o notation has no impact in 30 elements, here the prefactor counts. O(n) is equivalent to  c*F(n). for 30 elements c dominates the total search time.

Comment: @AlexWien I'm talking about Binary Search in general, not particularly in this case

Comment: You should answer his question, not the general. For his case the O(log n) is misleading!

Answer (score 1):

Linear search is defenitely the best choice if that's the array of 30 primitive types.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use Binary search if you don't know the range of your input numbers. or if array is indeed sorted.
2. If you know range of your numbers. then hash must be a better option.

For Hash : you can either use C++ Container "Set" if you are programming in c++. or else you can simply use array for your job in which you have to mark the element which is present. and for searching it simply check whether flag for that element is set or unset !